# How to display images in production with electron, react and electron-builder

Tags: reactjs, image, electron, assets, electron-builder

I'm very new to electron and I've a React + Electron application that I want to package with electron builder. But the problem is that images don't display after the application is packaged.

**1. Folder structure**

```
---node modules/
|
---build/
|
---dist/
|
---src/
|
---public/
|   |
|   ---assets/
|   |  |
|   |  ---images/  
|   |
|   ---electron.js
|   |
|   ---favicon.ico
|   |
|   ---index.html
|   
---package.json
```

**2. How I access images in dev**

I've images in `public/assets/images`

To access it in my code I do:

```js
import MyImage from "assets/images/my_image.png"

export function Image() {
   return (<img src={MyImage} />)
}
```

**3. How I'm building my app**

Here is an excerpt of the script and build part of my package.json file:

```json
 ...
 "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "electron-dev": "concurrently \"yarn start\" \"wait-on http://localhost:3000 && electron .\"",
    "preelectron-build": "yarn build",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "electron-build": "electron-builder"
  },
 "build": {
    ...
    "files": [
      "dist/**/*"
    ],
    "directories": {
      "buildResources": "build",  
      "output": "dist"

    },
    "extraResources": [
      "./public/assets/**"
    ]
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: please try `"./public/assets/**/*"`

Comment: @Medi Is there something I should change in the way I'm importing images  in the code after doing this ?

Answer (score 2):

Make the following changes to your `extraResources` section:

```
"extraResources": [
      {
        "from": "./public/assets",
        "to": "assets"
      }
]
```

This will copy the contents of assets in the resources directory of your production build. After this make the following changes to the way you are importing the assets:

```
const { app } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');

const ASSETS_PATH = app.isPackaged ?
    path.join(process.resourcesPath, 'assets') :
    path.join(app.getAppPath(), `public${path.sep}assets`);

import MyImage from path.join(ASSETS_PATH, `images/my_image.png`);
```